# REST API routing with params good practice

Tags: api, rest, routes, backend

There's routing for my server:

```
/api/debts/:id
```

to get info about particular debt and

```
/api/debts/search?searchData=something
```

to search debts by something.

And first route always handles search requests. I want to change it and know how to do it in several ways (just remove /api/debts in the second route etc) but I want to know a good practice for this.

UPD: There's also the route

```
/api/debts
```

to get all debts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change it and know how to do it in several ways (just remove /api/debts in the second route etc) but I want to know a good practice for this.

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

So if you decide, in the support of other concerns, that you want to use a different [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), then go ahead and do that.

```
/debts/search?searchData=something
/search/debts?searchData=something
```

Those are both *fine*.  Sticking additional path-segments like `api` on the front is also *fine*.  General purpose clients don't care, because they are just copying the identifier into the [request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)

---

> this is not considered good, because it has search which it verb

Consider the URI below

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/search

This *works*, and exactly the way you would expect, even though "search" happens to be a verb (sometimes) in the English language.

It's even ok to use registered HTTP methods in your identifiers:

```
GET /dictionary/delete HTTP/1.1
Host: www.merriam-webster.com
```

You can try that one in your web browser by clicking on
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delete

What *doesn't* work particularly well is assuming that the identifier defines the request semantics; the [request method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) is the appropriate mechanism for communicating the request semantics, not the identifier.  In other words

```
GET /delete
```

is a request that promises [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics; if you handle that request by making a bunch of destructive edits, then that's a [fault of the implementation](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

---

The confusion here is not Raj's fault, of course -- there is a LOT of literature on the web that (a) describes arbitrary spelling constraints for resource identifiers and (b) cites "REST" as an authority for those constraints.

Part (b) has no factual basis - it's just folklore that has gained traction.

REST doesn't care about spelling conventions for your identifiers in the same way that compilers don't care about spelling conventions for your variable names.

REST cares a lot about when two identifiers are the same, because [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234), and particularly [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) are important things for the general purpose components to be able to do correctly.

But the machines don't distinguish between nouns, verbs, hmac codes, rot13 ciphers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For search or filter purposes `/api/debts?searchData=something` is preferred.

In `/api/debts/search?searchData=something`, this is not considered good, because it has `search` which it `verb` and the `searchData` is outside the `resources`.

For details please refer
[here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mark that I also have the route: GET /api/debts to get all debts. And it handles request before  /api/debts?searchData=something

Comment: Still, single resource should be working, while receiving request params they can received in a `Map`, this way if there are no incoming params, you can return all `debts` other wise return results after filtering or searching etc...